# Obtain low and high order nybbles from byte within Java ByteBuffer

Tags: java, byte, mask, bytebuffer, bit-shift

I need to extract two integer values from a byte stored within a ByteBuffer (little endian order)

```
ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.wrap(inputBuffer);
bb.order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN);
```

The values I need to obtain from any byte within the ByteBuffer are:

**length = integer value of low order nibble**

**frequency = integer value of high order nibble**

At the moment I'm extracting the low order nybble with this code:

```
length = bb.getInt(index) & 0xf;
```

Which seems to work perfectly well.  It is however the high order nybble that I seem to be having trouble interpreting correctly.

I get a bit confused with bit shifting or masking, which I think I need to perform, and any advice would be super helpful.

Thanks muchly!!

Comment: Please post the code you tried and describe exactly what's wrong with it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> I need to extract two integer values from a byte

So you need to get a byte not an int, and the byte order doesn't matter.

```
int lowNibble = bb.get(index) & 0x0f; // the lowest 4 bits
int hiNibble = (bb.get(index) >> 4) & 0x0f; // the highest 4 bits.
```

Comment: Thanks Peter, just the ticket!!

Answer (score 1):

To get the high order nibble, all you need to do is bit shift; the low order bits will simply fall off.

```
int val = 0xAB;
int lo = val & 0xF;
int hi = val >> 4;
System.out.println("hi is " + Integer.toString(hi, 16));
System.out.println("lo is " + Integer.toString(lo, 16));
```

Comment: see what happens with `int val = (byte) 0xAB;` ;)